ReadyApI/Soapui junit report with maven
i'am trying to implement CI for my test automation project using maven with bamboo.
I need to generate the junit report to parse it in bamboo.
I'am using this POM:
`
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId><artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId></artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- Do not change. Commands the Maven plugin to run a functional test. -->
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>${soapui.projectfile}</projectFile>
                            <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                            <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/Junit</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

but the junit report generated is like report for config like that :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="UC_APIS.APIS" tests="2" failures="0" errors="0" time="52.542">
    <properties>
        <property name="jansi.mode" value="force"/>
        <property name="java.runtime.name" value="OpenJDK Runtime Environment"/>
        <property name="sun.boot.library.path" value="C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\bin"/>
        <property name="java.vm.version" value="25.252-b09"/>
        <property name="maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory" value="C:\github\ndc-automated-tests"/>
        <property name="java.vm.vendor" value="AdoptOpenJDK"/>
        <property name="java.vendor.url" value="http://java.oracle.com/"/>
        <property name="guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check" value="true"/>
        <property name="path.separator" value=";"/>
        <property name="java.vm.name" value="OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM"/>
        <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io"/>
        <property name="user.country" value="FR"/>
        <property name="user.script" value=""/>
        <property name="sun.java.launcher" value="SUN_STANDARD"/>
        <property name="sun.os.patch.level" value=""/>
        <property name="java.vm.specification.name" value="Java Virtual Machine Specification"/>
        <property name="user.dir" value="C:\github\ndc-automated-tests"/>
        <property name="java.runtime.version" value="1.8.0_252-b09"/>
        <property name="java.awt.graphicsenv" value="sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment"/>
        <property name="java.endorsed.dirs" value="C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\endorsed"/>
        <property name="os.arch" value="amd64"/>
        <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="C:\Users\T143445\AppData\Local\Temp\"/>
        <property name="line.separator" value="
"/>
        <property name="java.vm.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation"/>
        <property name="user.variant" value=""/>
        <property name="os.name" value="Windows 10"/>
        <property name="classworlds.conf" value="C:\Users\T143445\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.1.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.launching\launches\m2conf14516691068751872087.tmp"/>
        <property name="jansi.force" value="true"/>
        <property name="sun.jnu.encoding" value="Cp1252"/>
        <property name="java.library.path" value="C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/devtools/sts//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.3.v20220515-1416/jre/bin/server;C:/devtools/sts//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.3.v20220515-1416/jre/bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\TNC Client Plugin\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\T143445\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\T143445\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\T143445\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\devtools\sts;;."/>
        <property name="jansi.passthrough" value="true"/>
        <property name="sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons" value="true"/>
        <property name="java.specification.name" value="Java Platform API Specification"/>
        <property name="java.class.version" value="52.0"/>
        <property name="sun.management.compiler" value="HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers"/>
        <property name="os.version" value="10.0"/>
        <property name="user.home" value="C:\Users\T143445"/>
        <property name="user.timezone" value="Europe/Paris"/>
        <property name="java.awt.printerjob" value="sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob"/>
        <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="java.specification.version" value="1.8"/>
        <property name="org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks" value="true"/>
        <property name="java.class.path" value="C:\devtools\sts\plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319\jars\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar"/>
        <property name="user.name" value="T143445"/>
        <property name="java.vm.specification.version" value="1.8"/>
        <property name="sun.java.command" value="org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -B --threads 8 com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test clean test -Dstyle.color=always -Dstyle.color=always"/>
        <property name="java.home" value="C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre"/>
        <property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="64"/>
        <property name="user.language" value="fr"/>
        <property name="java.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation"/>
        <property name="awt.toolkit" value="sun.awt.windows.WToolkit"/>
        <property name="java.vm.info" value="mixed mode"/>
        <property name="java.version" value="1.8.0_252"/>
        <property name="java.ext.dirs" value="C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext"/>
        <property name="sun.boot.class.path" value="C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\devtools\jdk8u252-b09\jre\classes"/>
        <property name="java.vendor" value="AdoptOpenJDK"/>
        <property name="maven.home" value="C:\github\ndc-automated-tests\EMBEDDED"/>
        <property name="style.color" value="always"/>
        <property name="file.separator" value="\"/>
        <property name="java.vendor.url.bug" value="http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/"/>
        <property name="sun.io.unicode.encoding" value="UnicodeLittle"/>
        <property name="sun.cpu.endian" value="little"/>
        <property name="sun.desktop" value="windows"/>
        <property name="sun.cpu.isalist" value="amd64"/>
    </properties>
    <testcase name="UC2" time="26.063"/>
    <testcase name="UC1" time="26.479"/>
</testsuite>

When i use the Junit parser after build in test part i have limited information :
enter image description here
We need to have detailled test report with succes and failed test.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Best regards,
Smilnik
`
I tried but the junit report is not detailling steps of test
